# how to retrieve data from mysql to java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am making a java program about library computer seat monitoring. If the library custodian enters the student's student number, he/she will be logged in and his/her firstname and lastname will be displayed on a JLabel in java GUI. The student number, firstname and lastname are all in the database. How will I retrieve those data from tha database and store it to the JLabel?

Comment: What have you tried? From the question, it looks like you need to learn the basic concepts of Swing, JDBC. If you are facing any specific issue, please update the question with details.

Comment: Looking at the comments, you are already capable of retrieving the data from the database (which you should have mentioned in your question). What else is left ?

Answer (score 4):

What something simple? Use [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)

Here's an example from that wikipedia page:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:mysql:myhostname1",
     "myLogin",
     "myPassword" );
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
try {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM MyTable" );
    try {
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {
               // Column numbers start at 1.
               // Also there are many methods on the result set to return
               //  the column as a particular type. Refer to the Sun documentation
               //  for the list of valid conversions.
               System.out.println( "COLUMN " + i + " = " + rs.getObject(i) );
            }
        }
    } finally {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) { /* Propagate the original exception
instead of this one that you may want just logged */ }
    }
} finally {
    try { stmt.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) { /* Propagate the original exception
instead of this one that you may want just logged */ }
}
```

Comment: yes i used JDBC. And i also tried to retrieve a data from the database and it worked. But the thing is i dont know how to retrieve it in a JLabel.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. I believe there is a [setText method on JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) that should do what you want...?

Comment: logan has done you a favor.  If you have data from the database, you've solved half the problem.  Now you just need to update the Swing UI with the label value.

Comment: @logan yes, but i dont know what is the appropriate syntax to put inside the setText method

Comment: @MaverickAbella the appropriate syntax ?? That method accepts one parameter, which is a `String`. How hard can it be ?

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment on the other answer (+1 to logan) here is some pseudo to show the logic to store results in a `JLabel`:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable");

StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();//create string buffer to hold results

//use html to enable newlines in jlabel
 sb.append("<html>");

while (rs.next()) {
     sb.append(rs.getString("a")).append("<br>");//append results to buffer
 }
 sb.append("</html>");

 //create label with results
 JLabel label=new JLabel(sb.toString());
```

Alternatively you can create the `JLabel` first and call [`JLabel#setText(String text);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) on its instance:

```
JLabel label=new JLabel();

//read results to buffer

label.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Please mention in your pseudo-code that the database query and the update of the `JLabel` should happen on different `Thread`s. The update of the label should happen on the EDT, and the EDT will not be happy doing database calls.

Comment: Also note that a `JLabel` isn't a multi-line component, so the `append("\n")` call is rather useless.